# Python decompile PYC file with references to other files

Tags: python, pyc

A file I had got corrupted, and the only backup I have is in the pychache folder. I have tried to use uncompyle6 and it gave an error seen below. I'm not sure what the cause of this is, but I'm assuming that this is because it references variables or functions from other files. How do I decompile the file with references to other files?

```
Parse error at or near `POP_EXCEPT' instruction at offset 1476

        @osutracker.before_loop
        async def before_printer(self):
            print('waiting...')
            await self.bot.wait_until_ready()

# file osu.cpython-38.pyc
# Deparsing stopped due to parse error
```

File: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/437091189792047125/782360883861913640/osu.cpython-38.pyc

Comment: Why don’t you try generating a new pyc in a sandbox env and see how uncompyle6 handles references to other files. Maybe those other files have to be available to uncompyle6?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this for now by using unncompyle6 with the cpython-37 rather than the -38. I'm not sure why this worked, as uncompyle6 is supposed to support every version of python before 3.9, but it worked.

Comment: Have you ever used google translate to translate the same text to couple of different languages and noticed that some translations to some langauges will work but some languages to others won't. Even though google translate is supposed to support those different languages? 

It's pretty much that here.